# Is it possible to have different color values for a font-lock face in a string?

Tags: faces, font-lock, colors

My `font-lock-warning-face` has a red color. Which works well in almost all circumstances, it is very pronounced.

The problem is, my `font-lock-string-face` has orange color. So warnings inside strings are hardly visible, because orange is similar to red. For example, it is hard to notice a regexp problem around `\`.

Is it possible to have a different foreground color in `font-lock-warning-face`, if the warning is inside a string?

Look at this screen shot, here the `\` has a different color, which is hardly noticable. I'd like to use a very different warning color (maybe a red background color) in this case (I don't want to change my string color, neither my global warning color).

[image: problem]

Comment: What major-mode (and/or minor-mode, if applicable) are you using that generates the warning relating to the backslash that is the subject of your question?  E.g., `lisp-interaction-mode`; or, perhaps `emacs-lisp-mode`?  The solution may need to be custom tailored to that major-mode and/or minor-mode (if applicable).

Comment: @lawlist: currently this is an issue in `emacs-lisp-mode`. But if I manage to get a solution, I may extend this to c-mode, for example (like marking invalid escape sequences, format specifiers in strings).